# Calculate deltaE94 in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, calculation

I'm trying to calculate the Cie94 Delta-E from two colors eg. `hexA` and `hexB` - somewhere I found some code which I tried to adjust. Somehow the calculated results aren't correct. My reference is this site: http://colormine.org/delta-e-calculator/cie94

For all who don't know what this deltaE is: on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) is a good explanation. The trick is to get this formula from the CIE94 section in to javascript.

**This function calculates the deltaE:**

```
//DeltaE94 calculate
$.fn.deltaE94 = function(hexA, hexB) {
  var labA = rgb2lab(hex2Rgb(hexA));
  var labB = rgb2lab(hex2Rgb(hexB));

  var deltaL = labA[0] - labB[0];
  var deltaA = labA[1] - labB[1];
  var deltaB = labA[2] - labB[2];
  var c1 = Math.sqrt(labA[1] * labA[1] + labA[2] * labA[2]);
  var c2 = Math.sqrt(labB[1] * labB[1] + labB[2] * labB[2]);
  var deltaC = c1 - c2;
  var deltaH = deltaA * deltaA + deltaB * deltaB - deltaC * deltaC;
  deltaH = deltaH < 0 ? 0 : Math.sqrt(deltaH);
  var sc = 1.0 + 0.045 * c1;
  var sh = 1.0 + 0.015 * c1;
  var deltaLKlsl = deltaL / (1.0);
  var deltaCkcsc = deltaC / (sc);
  var deltaHkhsh = deltaH / (sh);
  var i = deltaLKlsl * deltaLKlsl + deltaCkcsc * deltaCkcsc + deltaHkhsh * deltaHkhsh;
  return i < 0 ? 0 : Math.sqrt(i);
}
```

**Color conversation:**

```
//HEX color to RGB
function hex2Rgb(hex) {
  hex = hex.replace(/[^0-9A-F]/gi, '');
  var bigint = parseInt(hex, 16);
  var r = (bigint >> 16) & 255;
  var g = (bigint >> 8) & 255;
  var b = bigint & 255;

  return [r, g, b].join();
}

//converse rgb to lab
function rgb2lab(rgb){
  let r = rgb[0] / 255, g = rgb[1] / 255, b = rgb[2] / 255, x, y, z;
  r = (r > 0.04045) ? Math.pow((r + 0.055) / 1.055, 2.4) : r / 12.92;
  g = (g > 0.04045) ? Math.pow((g + 0.055) / 1.055, 2.4) : g / 12.92;
  b = (b > 0.04045) ? Math.pow((b + 0.055) / 1.055, 2.4) : b / 12.92;
  x = (r * 0.4124 + g * 0.3576 + b * 0.1805) / 0.95047;
  y = (r * 0.2126 + g * 0.7152 + b * 0.0722) / 1.00000;
  z = (r * 0.0193 + g * 0.1192 + b * 0.9505) / 1.08883;
  x = (x > 0.008856) ? Math.pow(x, 1/3) : (7.787 * x) + 16/116;
  y = (y > 0.008856) ? Math.pow(y, 1/3) : (7.787 * y) + 16/116;
  z = (z > 0.008856) ? Math.pow(z, 1/3) : (7.787 * z) + 16/116;
  return [(116 * y) - 16, 500 * (x - y), 200 * (y - z)]
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$.fn.deltaE94('#983349', '#B03239');
```

- calculated: 1.0596
- expected:   9.3829

Comment: Instead of `return [r, g, b].join();` use `return [r, g, b];`

Comment: Ok that did the trick. Man you're good, I would never have found that.